# How to avoid random number while writing Dataframe for a given path in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark Dataframe by executing below code I am saving  the Dataframe in give path.

```
df.write.format("csv").options(header='false', inferschema='true',sep="|").option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("path")
```

after saving files in path folder when i am list the files by executing `ls -ltr` command.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 administrator administrator 101 May 16 12:47 part-00002-41096c1e-314a-4191-bd50-2ecc2c23b760-c000.csv.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 administrator administrator 201 May 16 12:47 part-00000-41096c1e-314a-4191-bd50-2ecc2c23b760-c000.csv.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 administrator administrator 227 May 16 12:47 part-00005-41096c1e-314a-4191-bd50-2ecc2c23b760-c000.csv.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 administrator administrator 214 May 16 12:47 part-00004-41096c1e-314a-4191-bd50-2ecc2c23b760-c000.csv.gz
```

my output file contain some random number like `'41096c1e-314a-4191-bd50-2ecc2c23b760-c000`'. How to avoid this random number in file name i.e
I am expecting my output file should be `part-00001.gz,part-00002.gz etc or part-00001.csv.gz,part-00002.csv.gz`

Please help me on this.how to achieve this?